# Having trouble mounting .ISO file when using QEMU

Tags: macos, shell, arm, qemu, apple-m1

**I'm running a MacBook Air M1 with Big Sur 11.4 installed**

I'm trying to mount an ISO image of the Virtio-Win networking driver, using the following commands in my start.sh file.

```
  -drive file=/Users/username/Downloads/windows-10/virtio-win-0.1.190.iso,media=cdrom,if=none,id=drivers \
  -device usb-storage,drive=drivers
```

The drive does not show up when I run the QEMU Windows 10 ARM instance, everything else works just fine.
Are there other options for moving files or images from my host to the QEMU instance?

Comment: Try run the `SimpleHTTPServer` in you host by `python -m SimpleHTTPServer PORT` under the drive file path( **/Users/username/Downloads/** ), and open the `host:PORT` in the QEMU instance's browser and download the file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to use `-cdrom` and `-boot d`
This works for me:

```
         -bios ./bios.fd \
         -drive if=virtio,format=raw,file=./debian.qcow2,discard=on \
         -cdrom ./ubuntu-21.04-live-server-arm64.iso \
         -boot d
```